# unable to call 'queryInstalledChaincodes' on hyperledger-fabric node-sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

According to hyperledger-fabric node-sdk documentation both functions 
'queryChannels' and 'queryInstalledChaincodes' must be called by admin. I am 
able to access 'queryChannels'(both from the Client class) but on accessing 
queryInstalledChaincodes, an error occurs saying :

(status: 500, message: Authorization for GETINSTALLEDCHAINCODES on channel getinstalledchaincodes has been denied with error Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin])

Can somebody propose a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is sample, you should find out which identity you are using for the client.

The problem is your fabric ACL policy(which is in the `configtx.yaml`) has set the chaincode area to a Admin access.
Which means you should use the admin identity to call the `queryInstalledChaincodes` function.

Further infos please check this page:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/access_control.html#what-is-an-access-control-list

Also this question has been asked 1 year, 6 months ago, so I bet you have worked it out on your own, congrats!